# VirtualBox仮想マシンのOS起動完了を検知する方法

Tags: linux, shellscript, virtualbox

### 知りたいこと

VirtualBox仮想マシン（以下VM)のOSが起動完了したことを検知する方法

---

### 状況

VirtualBoxでVMを立ち上げて開発等の作業をしています。

今まで作業開始時に、VMの立ち上げ、SSHログイン等を手動で行ってきましたが、自動化できないかと思い、シェルスクリプトにて実現しようとしていますが、一つ壁に当たりました。

**VMのOSが起動完了したタイミングが分からない。**

というものです。

SSHで接続するところまで自動化しようとすると、OSが（sshdと言ったほうがいいのでしょうか？）起動完了しているかがわからないとSSHが弾かれます。

Virtualboxで仮想マシンが起動完了したことを確認するコマンドはあるのですが、これはあくまでマシンが立ち上がったことを確認できるものであり、OSが立ち上がったかどうかを確認するものではないようです。

---

### 現状での妥協案 シェルスクリプト

現状では「**OSが立ち上がってる≒SSHでの接続が可能**」という認識のもと、逆転の発想で「**OSが立ち上がっていない≒SSH接続が弾かれる**」という状況を利用しています。

自分の環境ではVMのOSが起動に大体1分くらいかかるので、まず1分ウエイトしてから、SSH接続が成立するまで繰り返し試行する方法をとるものです。以下は下手で恥ずかしいですが、作成したシェルスクリプトです。

```
#!/bin/bash

white_green="\e[37;42;1m"
white_red="\e[37;41;1m"
colorEnd="\e[m"

#引数確認
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    /bin/echo -e "${white_red}VM名を指定してください${colorEnd}"
    exit 1
fi

VBoxManage list vms | grep "$1";isvms=$?
if [ $isvms -ne 0 ]; then
    /bin/echo -e "${white_red}指定されたVM名は存在しません${colorEnd}"
    /bin/echo -e "${white_red}存在するVM名は以下です${colorEnd}"
    VBoxManage list vms
    exit 1
fi

#起動確認
VBoxManage list runningvms | grep "$1";isRunning=$?
if [ $isRunning -eq 0 ]; then
    /bin/echo -e "${white_red}$1はすでに起動しています${colorEnd}"
    exit 1
fi

#VM起動
VBoxManage startvm "$1" --type headless > /dev/null 2>&1
/bin/echo -e "${white_green}VM起動${colorEnd}"
#OSが起動するまでに約１分かかるのでウエイトを挟む
e=0
/bin/echo -e "${white_green}OS起動待機中(60秒待ちます)${colorEnd}"
for e in 0 5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 50 55 60; do
    echo -n "$e秒…\r" 
    sleep 5s
done

#ssh接続
vmname="ssh -p22 -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa hoge@host"
count=0
/bin/echo -e "${white_green}ssh接続中…${colorEnd}"
until eval ${vmname}
do
    echo -n "…"
    sleep 5s    
    count=$((count+1))
    if [ $count -gt 20 ]; then
    /bin/echo -e "${white_red}20回試行したがダメでした${colorEnd}"
    exit 255
    fi    
done 

exit 0
```

---

### ベストプラクティスは？

一応目的は果たせているのですが、SSHの接続可否を用いるのはいまいちスマートではないように感じています。

VMのOSが立ち上がったタイミングを取得できる方法をご存知のかたよろしくおねがいします。

Comment: 繋がるまでリトライでもいいと思います。それかVMのOSの/etc/rc.localなどに”起動完了"を通知するスクリプトを仕込むとか, cronで定期的にハートビートを送信するとか。どこに通知するのかはいろいろあると思いますが。大げさなことをやるならSNMPとかNagiosとか...

Comment: @Kenji Noguchi さん ありがとうございます。あながち間違いでもないのですね。cronは考えたのですが、できるだけ外部から検知する方法が望ましかった状況でした。SNMP、Nagiosは不勉強であまりわかりませんが、今の自分の知識レベルではちょっと手に余りそうです…。/etc/rc.localについては思いつかなかったので、勉強して見たいと思います。

Comment: 質問と関係ないのですが `#!/bin/bash` であれば `/bin/echo` (外部コマンド)でなくても `echo` (bash 組込みコマンド) で充分かつ効率的だと思います。

Answer (score 4):

一般論として「ＯＳが起動した」ということをどう定義しましょうか。
- OS Kernel 部がロードされた状況（まだ daemon/service 類は起動していない）
- コンソールログインができる状況
- GUI ログインができる状況
- 使いたい daemon/service 類が接続を受け付ける状況

今回の場合、使いたいのは [ssh](/questions/tagged/ssh) なので
- [ssh](/questions/tagged/ssh) で接続しようとして、できたら [ssh](/questions/tagged/ssh) 起動済み
というのが最適（つまり現状が最適）だと、オイラ個人としては思います。

同様
- [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) に接続しようとして、できたら [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) 起動済み
- [http](/questions/tagged/http) 接続しようとして、できたら [apache](/questions/tagged/apache) 起動済み
ってことだと思います ([mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) や [apache](/questions/tagged/apache) が自動起動/手動起動のどっちでも）。

こういうとき、よく `ping` が通ったら・・・という回答を見かけますが
`ping` が通ってもそれは単に `ICMP` 起動済みでという意味でしかないのであまり役に立たないっす。
（目的のサービスはまだ実行されていないかもしれない）

使いたいサービスに対して接続できたらＯＫ以上に確実な方法は無いでしょう。

Comment: @774RRさん　ありがとうございます。おっしゃるとおりsshdが起動していれば目的に合致する状態です。Pingは試しましたが、うまく行きませんでした…。行き着いたSSH接続試行でも悪い選択ではないようで安心しました。